# expandable animated header in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am working on a **wordpress** theme and want to know how can I add an axpandable(by click) animated header. 
some thing like

```
http://www.alkhaleejsugar.ae/en/gulf-sugar-suppliers-uae
```

after loading . 
how can do it in wordpress. or is there any **theme** supports that ?

Comment: Do you know how to view the source code of a web site?

Comment: where to change main page HTMLs in a .zip wordpress theme?

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking (please, read **[ask]**), but you can track down the code that does the animated header and add it to your own code (*"I'm workin on a **wordpress** theme"*). Then update your question with those improvements.